# How to refactor method with more than 6 parameters in the kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, refactoring

I need to make a request in an api, and I have to send 11 parameters, but using a code analysis tool, inform that I must send a maximum of 6. There would be some form of refactoring for me to send these parameters without being sent this way? I'm using kotlin
I simplified my code:

```
viewModel.requestTest(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param10)
```

```
class viewModel

fun requestTest (param1 , param2, param3 : String? = "" , param4 : String? = "", param5 : String? = "", param6 : String? = "", param7 : String? = "", param8 : String? = "", param9 : String? = "", param10 : String? = "" , param10: String? = "") {
    //do request filling the body with these parameters
}
```

Comment: Did you try passing named parameters instead of positional parameters?  With named parameters, there's really no reason for that limit.

Comment: hello, I didn't understand your question exactly, but I edited in my question how is my "requestTest" method in my viewModel.

Comment: does your tool complain about the place where you declared the method, or the place where you call it?

Comment: reclama que tem muitos parametros no metodo, é coloca que o ideal é 6. 
on this site explains (it would be the LongParameterList) : https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/complexity.html#longparameterlist

Comment: `ignoreDataClasses` defaults to `true`, so @Raman's answer will probably work

Comment: @ramossuit You completely changed the question, which would now require me to rewrite my answer -- please don't do that. Its a better approach to accept the answer I provided since it worked for you to solve your original problem, and post a new question for your new problem. I've edited your question to revert it, but you can use your question history to copy and post a new question (or you can find existing answers for your new question, which I'm reasonably certain already exist).

Comment: sorry, Raman, I accepted your answer. I will create a new question, if you know this new problem I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data class as a wrapper for the parameters.

```kotlin
data class RequestParams(val param1: String, ..., val paramN: String)

fun requestTest (params: RequestParams) {
    // use parameters like params.param1
}
```

Note, you can also provide default values for those parameters and use named arguments to simplify this type of call in most cases e.g.

```kotlin
data class RequestParams(
  val name: String = "foo",
  val value: Int = 3,
  ...,
  val whatever: String? = null)

val params = RequestParams(
  value = 5
)

...
```

Note that you are still passing more than 6 parameters to the constructor of the data class, but usually linting tools will recognize that data classes are an idiomatic way to hold many properties, and ignore them when checking this rule (as noted by @Matt Timmermans in the comments of your question, this is [indeed the case](https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/complexity.html#longparameterlist)).

If that does not solve your problem, then you could group your 10 parameters into 2 data classes, with 5+5 or 4+6 parameters -- whether that makes any sense all depends on the underlying business meaning of your parameters.

If it does not make sense to split the parameters that way, I'd tend to add a linter ignore annotation on the data class constructor rather than coding specifically to work around the linter.

Comment: would the RequestParams data class stay inside my viewModel?

Comment: It can be wherever you like. If it only has meaning inside the view model, feel free to define it there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I said in the question I am using a detection tool that does not allow more than 6 parameters in the method ... Using this "data class" that comes with the 11 parameters would not give the same error?

Comment: hello renan, i did what you told me, but it created another problem, i edited the question to exemplify

Answer (score 0):

i think that it is useful to use Object like Bundle(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle?hl=en) in Android system